# Get XML value using ElementTree in Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have this XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<feed xml:base="https://receasy1p1942606901trial.hanatrial.ondemand.com:443/rec/Accrual_PO.xsodata/"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <title type="text">accruals_po</title>
    <id>https://receasy1p1942606901trial.hanatrial.ondemand.com:443/rec/Accrual_PO.xsodata/accruals_po</id>
    <author>
        <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="self" title="accruals_po" href="accruals_po" />
    <entry>
        <id>https://receasy1p1942606901trial.hanatrial.ondemand.com:443/rec/Accrual_PO.xsodata/accruals_po('96372537-120')</id>
        <title type="text"></title>
        <author>
            <name />
        </author>
        <link rel="edit" title="accruals_po" href="accruals_po('96372537-120')"/>
        <category term="receasy.accruals_poType" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:PO_NUMBER m:type="Edm.String">96372537-120</d:PO_NUMBER>
                <d:SAP_AMT m:type="Edm.Single">109</d:SAP_AMT>
                <d:GL_ACCOUNT m:type="Edm.Int64">65009000</d:GL_ACCOUNT>
                <d:COMPANY_CODE m:type="Edm.String">US10_OH</d:COMPANY_CODE>
                <d:CONFIRMED_ACCRUAL_AMT m:type="Edm.Single">109</d:CONFIRMED_ACCRUAL_AMT>
                <d:FINAL_APPROVER m:type="Edm.String">europe\bamcguir</d:FINAL_APPROVER>
                <d:FINAL_GL_ACCOUNT m:type="Edm.Int64">65009000</d:FINAL_GL_ACCOUNT>
                <d:FINAL_COMPANY_CODE m:type="Edm.String">US10_OH</d:FINAL_COMPANY_CODE>
                <d:RECONCILIATION m:type="Edm.String">Successful</d:RECONCILIATION>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

I'm trying to get the values highlighted below in bold, they are under the entry tag.

**96372537-120**

**109**

**65009000**

**US10_OH**

**109**

**europe\bamcguir**

**65009000**

**US10_OH**

**Successful**

This is the code I have as of now to get the values.

```
import urllib2
import xmltodict
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import requests

tree = ET.parse('export.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root:
    print child.tag, child.attrib
    for child2 in child:
        print child2.tag, child2.attrib
        for child3 in child2:
            print child3.tag, child3.attrib
            for child4 in child3:
                print child4.tag, child4.attrib
                for child5 in child4:
                    print child5.tag, child5.attrib
```

This is part of the output that I get for PO_NUMBER.

```
{http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices}PO_NUMBER {'{http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata}type': 'Edm.String'}
```

I'm not able to get the value of PO_NUMBER which is **96372537-120**. How do I get this value, and the other values as highlighted above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ElementTree, an element's (leading) text node is set on the `text` attribute. `tag` is the name of the XML tag (in Clark's notation) and `attrib` are the XML attributes only (also in Clark's notation).

So `child5.text` will give you the information you need.

Incidentally, you can use Clark's notation `{namespace}tag` with ElementTree's regular querying API to access the content or properties element directly, you don't have to iterate everything by hand:

```
tree.iter('{http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata}properties')
```

will give you an iterator on all the "properties" objects in the tree, and then you can just iterate on each property and get the corresponding child's text:

```
for child in property:
    print(child.text)
```

Note an oddity for mixed content (when an element can have both text and element children): in the ElementTree document model, only *first child* is set on `.text` when it's a text node, otherwise it's set as `.tail` on the preceding element e.g.

```
<foo>
    bar
    <qux/>
    baz
</foo>
```

will have `foo.text == "bar"` but "baz" will be set on `qux.tail`.

Comment: got it by using child4.text. Thank you so much for this explanation! Really appreciate it!

Comment: `tree.iter('{http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices}*')` will also do.

Comment: @Tomalak Indeed but I assumed they may have wanted to group/segregate values by property.

Comment: Agreed, this only works when there is no more than one `<m:properties>` element in the document.